# Setting up Eclipse with Lua for the first time

Tags: eclipse, lua

I'm trying to set up the [Lua Development Tools / Koneki](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/) for the first time. I'm new to Eclipse, but I've made a bunch of Lua programs from the command line before.

Hopefully my problem is a generic Eclipse one that someone might be able to help with.

**What I did:**

After downloading LDT, I followed the short [set-up guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/User_Guide#Execution_Environment). I downloaded the suggested [Lua 5.1 zip](http://sierrawireless.github.com/lua-execution-environments/). I added 5.1 as an execution environment following the set-up guide.

**Problem:**

I cannot run any Lua projects. When I hit the green Run or Debug buttons, Koneki says "This selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." It seems this is a generic Eclipse error.

When I click the drop-down arrow on the Run button, only "Run configurations" is available, and on that Run Configurations pane I cannot add a run configuration, the New button is greyed out.

---

Please can someone give more information on how to debug or fix this kind of error in Eclipse? I get the feeling I've missed some step that might be obvious to people who know Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have a script in the script explorer on the left? If not post a screenshot with a little script in it - I'll compare it to mine

Comment: I have a main.lua under src/ on the left, that was the setup for the default Lua project that LDT/Koneki creates. Here's a shot with the config box too: http://imgur.com/G8wBx

Comment: As of the latest released milestone (0.9M1), LDT now supports the addition of external Lua interpreters, so you can say goodbye to the "The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" message!

More info here: http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2012/08/25/support-for-lua-interpreters-in-koneki-ldt-0-9m1

Comment: Thanks for the info kartben. I hope debugging works. Last time I checked it seemed to rely on Lua Socket which doesn't work with Lua 5.2

Comment: Hey Ben –– Debugging for Lua 5.2 is in the pipe... You can CC yourself on this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use this as a lua compiler - I use it to run embedded lua so when I tried to start a console script I got the same result as you.

Here's what I did - not sure if it's the best way but it works

Click Run/External Tools/External Tools Configurations...
A dialog box pops up
Put in

```
Name: lua
Location: /usr/local/bin/lua
Working Directory: ${container_loc}
Arguments: ${resource_name}
```

Then click on the green run drop down and select Run Configurations then in the dialog add a new configuration by clicking on the Add button on the right and select lua under the program list. Click Apply.

Now when you select main.lua and click on play it runs the lua script you've selected. Then after doing this I thought what happens if I read the manual and sure enough :-). click on help and Help Contents then in the help look at 'LDT user guide' and it tells you what to do there, a lot more elegantly than the above.

Hopefully this will get you started. cheers.

[Update: I tried the following the manual and it works for me. I put a print in, selected main.lua and clicked the green button and it prints hello in the console output below

```
local function main()
 print "hello"
end
main()
```

[Update2: no you need the external configuration stuff even after following the manual]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can get Hello world to print now. However at the end of your process, there's a difference to what I can see. Under Run Configurations, the Add button is greyed out. Weird. I now have a problem where I can't install luasocket that's required for debugging, because I'm running version 5.2 of Lua. -_-