# I have Lua extension how should I test it?

Tags: eclipse, lua

I do search on Google about this and tried many things but not succeed.
Even here I found a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854703/setting-up-eclipse-with-lua-for-the-first-time).

So in eclipse I can compile a hello world example but when I have a sample extension for vlc how can I run it in eclipse?
For example if I need to test [Example](http://addons.videolan.org/CONTENT/content-files/149618-time.lua)
How can I test this?

Sorry if this question is very easy for you but I am new to Lua and want to write an extension.

**UPDATE:**
One thing more I have tried online Lua compilers but they only tell me, my code compile successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug the VLC extension using [remote debugging instructions for ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging.html). I haven't tried this myself, but the author of [one of the extensions](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Resume+Media+V2?content=165231) has used ZBS to debug it.

Comment: Even this is not full answer but vlc is a way to test my code in lua, but what If I am not want to create extension for vlc?. Anyway thanks @Paul Kulchenko